# Column CHDRNUM or expression in SELECT list not valid. How I fixed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

```
SELECT 
    a.CHDRNUM, a.COWNNUM
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(H.ENTITYCODE) > 0
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
    END AS B
FROM 
    (SELECT CHDRNUM,COWNNUM 
     FROM CHDRPF)  AS a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ENTITYCODE, ENTITYTYPE, ISTATUS
     FROM ZBLSPF 
     WHERE ENTITYTYPE = 'CN' 
       AND ISTATUS IN ('RED', 'RED 1', 'RED 2', 'RED 3', 'RED 4', 'RED 5')) AS H ON H.ENTITYCODE = A.COWNNUM 
WHERE 
    a.CHDRNUM = '123';
```

Why are those 2 columns not included in the select list, but when I delete 2 columns (`CHDRNUM, COWNNUM`) it runs.

The error I get is

> Column CHDRNUM or expression in SELECT list not valid

Comment: Please setup a fiddle which demonstrates the issue and share the link.

Comment: You are using an aggregate function, so you need a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Unrelated, but: `FROM (SELECT CHDRNUM,COWNNUM FROM CHDRPF)  AS a` can be simplified to `FROM CHDRPF  AS a`

Comment: "*Column CHDRNUM or expression in SELECT list not valid*" does not sound like a Postgres error message. Postgres would complain with: "*column "a.chdrnum" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*". Which DBMS are you really using?